# Hodogram using ggplot2

Tags: r, vector, plot, direction

I would like to create a facetted plot using ggplot2, representing monthly wind hodograms.

I recently read the following post : [How to map wind direction and speed (velocity plot) with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050481/how-to-map-wind-direction-and-speed-velocity-plot-with-r). I think this is probably a good start for me. The following dataset represents windvalues as u and v components, with a timestep of 3 hours. I would like to represent it as an hodogram, meaning that each vector is following the previous one.

```
                u             v
 [1,]  -4.0000000 -6.928203e+00
 [2,]  -6.1283555 -5.142301e+00
 [3,]  -5.0000000  1.224647e-15
 [4,]  -3.7587705  1.368081e+00
 [5,]   4.0000000 -4.898587e-16
 [6,]   4.6984631 -1.710101e+00
 [7,]   5.6381557  2.052121e+00
 [8,]   6.1283555  5.142301e+00
 [9,]  -9.1925333 -7.713451e+00
[10,]  -6.5778483  2.394141e+00
[11,]  -5.3623111  4.499513e+00
[12,]  -4.5962667  3.856726e+00
[13,]  -7.0000000  1.714506e-15
[14,]  -6.5778483 -2.394141e+00
[15,]   6.0000000 -7.347881e-16
[16,]  -6.5778483 -2.394141e+00
[17,]  -6.0000000  1.469576e-15
[18,]  -8.0000000  1.959435e-15
[19,]  -5.6381557  2.052121e+00
[20,]  -6.0000000  1.469576e-15
[21,]  -4.5962667  3.856726e+00
[22,]   2.0000000 -3.464102e+00
[23,]   5.6381557 -2.052121e+00
[24,]   6.0000000 -7.347881e-16
[25,]   5.6381557 -2.052121e+00
[26,]  -5.3623111 -4.499513e+00
[27,]  -4.5962667 -3.856726e+00
[28,]  -6.1283555 -5.142301e+00
[29,]  -4.6984631 -1.710101e+00
[30,]   0.8682409 -4.924039e+00
[31,]   2.5000000 -4.330127e+00
[32,]  -0.8682409 -4.924039e+00
[33,]  -6.0000000  1.469576e-15
[34,]  -5.3623111 -4.499513e+00
[35,]  -3.8302222 -3.213938e+00
[36,]  -4.5962667 -3.856726e+00
[37,]  -3.5000000 -6.062178e+00
[38,]   1.0418891 -5.908847e+00
[39,]   5.3623111 -4.499513e+00
[40,]   4.5962667 -3.856726e+00
[41,]   3.8302222 -3.213938e+00
[42,]   3.0000000 -5.196152e+00
[43,]   5.3623111 -4.499513e+00
[44,]   5.3623111 -4.499513e+00
[45,]   4.5962667 -3.856726e+00
[46,]   3.0000000 -5.196152e+00
[47,]   4.5962667 -3.856726e+00
[48,]   3.8302222 -3.213938e+00
[49,]   1.0418891 -5.908847e+00
[50,]   3.8302222 -3.213938e+00
```

You can find a hodogram example here : [image] (like the one on the bottom left corner).

With these hodograms (1 per month), I would like to plot a facetted graph with ggplot2 but I think (I hope) that I can manage this part.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much by advance !

Comment: Perhaps you can show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Actually my problem is the begining, cause my initial dataset was a direction (0-360°)/intensity (m.s-1) table. I converted it in u and v vectors in order to try the "hodogram" command within the package "RSEIS". That package doesn't fit my needs and does not offer possibilities to customize. So i'm trying to find an hodogram code on internet but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my result. It needs some improvements, but I am close from the result I wanted as described in the post. Here is the code I used :

```
library("ggplot2")
library("plyr")
mydata <- read.table("C:\\myfile.csv", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
seasons <- mydata$seasons
years <- mydata$year
u <- mydata$u
v <- mydata$v
intensity <- mydata$intensity
wind <- cbind(u,v,intensity,seasons,years)
wind <- data.frame(wind)
x <- ddply(wind, .(years, seasons), summarize, x=cumsum(u*0.0108))
y <- ddply(wind, .(years, seasons), summarize, y=cumsum(v*0.0108))
x <- x$x
y <- y$y
wind <- cbind(wind,x,y)
wind <- data.frame(wind)
wind$seasons[wind$seasons == 1] <- "winter"
wind$seasons[wind$seasons == 2] <- "spring"
wind$seasons[wind$seasons == 3] <- "summer"
wind$seasons[wind$seasons == 4] <- "autumn"
p <- ggplot(wind, aes(x, y)) + geom_path(aes(colour = intensity))+ scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("blue","yellow","red"))
p + facet_grid(seasons ~ years)
```

Giving me the following result :

[image]

Thanks again to the Stackoverflow community which is always really reactive and helpfull !

Answer (score 2):

I got something, I'm still working on it...

```
u <- mydata$u
v <- mydata$v
x <- cumsum(mydata$u[56297:56704]*10.8)
y <- cumsum(mydata$v[56297:56704]*10.8)
wind <- cbind(x,y)
wind <- data.frame(wind)
p <- ggplot(wind) + geom_path(aes(x, y, colour = x))
```

[image]

To be continued... don't hesitate to comment !)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a concept of how I would do it. I will let you to fiddle with the details (like removing the title strips).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(MASS)

linedata <- data.frame(time = rep(1:200, 3), 
                       vals = runif(600), 
                       source = rep(letters[1:3], each = 200))

normdata <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n = 600, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5), ncol = 2)))
normdata$time <- rep(1:200, times = 3)
normdata$source = rep(letters[1:3], each = 200)
names(normdata)[1:2] <- c("x", "y")

linegraph <- ggplot(linedata, aes(x = time, y = vals)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ source, ncol = 1)

normgraph <- ggplot(normdata, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_path() +
  facet_wrap(~ source, ncol = 3)

grid.arrange(linegraph, normgraph, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you really much for your answer ! I still need the use of 'cumsum' in order to get a real hodogram, but your code will help me to get my final graph. I'll put my final result in the topic, thx again !