# Quiver / Arrow plot in R

Tags: r, plot, velocity

I am relatively new to R and am using version 3.0.2 on Windows 7. I am trying to map the velocity (speed and direction) of ocean currents, with longer arrows meaning stronger velocity.

I have tried doing this with the arrow-function in ggplot, like suggested in this post: [How to map wind direction and speed (velocity plot) with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050481/how-to-map-wind-direction-and-speed-velocity-plot-with-r)

However, it seems that this can only plot the same length arrow for all, so it will only give information about direction, not speed (unless I am misunderstood?). ggplot also seems to struggle with data in the format ncdf.

So I have tried a few other things, so far still without success. I think the quiver-function (package pracma) should be able to do what I am trying to, but I cannot seem to work out how to use it.

My data is a gridded ncdf file with the following dimensions:

```
 "file data_grid.nc has 2 dimensions:"
 "lat   Size: 61"
 "lon   Size: 121"
 "------------------------"
 "file data_grid.nc has 2 variables:"
 "double U[lat,lon]  Longname:U Missval:1e+30"
 "double V[lat,lon]  Longname:V Missval:1e+30"
```

Sorry I cannot give a reproducible example as my data file is very large. But I basically have Latitude and Longitude values and the corresponding zonal (West to East) velocity (U) and meridional (North to South) velocity (V).

I have tried (amongst a few other things):
    `quiver(lon, lat, U, V)`
which give me the error: 
`Error in x + scale * u : non-conformable arrays`

As in the post under the link above, I assume that U and V are wrong and need to be coordinates as well, but I honestly don't understand the explanation given in the package description (u, v : x,y-coordinates of start points).

Any idea where I might be going wrong?

A bit more information on the coding and format (*added on May 30th):
`Argo <- open.ncdf("data_grid.nc")`
`print.ncdf(Argo)` 
`lon = get.var.ncdf (Argo, "lon") # length =121`
`lat = get.var.ncdf (Argo, "lat") # length =61`
`U = get.var.ncdf (Argo, "U")  #dim (U) =  lat lon`
`V = get.var.ncdf (Argo, "V")  #dim(V) =  lat lon`
`U = t(U) #dim (U) = lon lat`
`V = t(V) #dim (U) = lon lat`

```
`dput(head(lon))` = `structure(c(150, 150.5, 151, 151.5, 152, 152.5), .Dim = 6L)`
`dput(head(lat))` = `structure(c(-30, -29.5, -29, -28.5, -28, -27.5), .Dim = 6L)`
`dput(head(U))`   = `structure(c(-4.329999924, -4.329999924, -4.329999924, -4.329999924,
```

-4.329999924, -4.329999924, -4.329999924, -4.329999924, -4.329999924, 
-4.329999924, -4.329999924, -4.329999924, -4.329999924, -4.329999924, 
-4.329999924, -4.329999924, -4.329999924, -3.400000095, -3.400000095, 
-3.400000095, -3.400000095, -3.400000095, -3.400000095, 0.129999995, 
0.129999995, 0.129999995, 0.129999995, 0.129999995, 0.129999995, 
0.129999995, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.100000001, 
0.100000001, 0.100000001, 0.100000001, 0.100000001, 0.100000001, 
-0.119999997, -0.119999997, -0.119999997, -0.119999997, -0.119999997, 
-0.119999997, -3.599999905, -3.599999905, -0.839999974, -0.839999974, 
2.680000067, 2.680000067, 1.24000001, -4.110000134, -3.599999905, 
-3.599999905, -0.839999974, -0.839999974, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 
1.24000001, -4.110000134, -4.110000134, -3.599999905, 1.24000001, 
1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 
1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 
1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 
1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.950000048, 
1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.24000001, 1.950000048, 
1.950000048, -3.650000095, -3.190000057, -2.279999971, -2.279999971, 
-2.279999971, -0.180000007, -3.650000095, -3.190000057, -3.190000057, 
-2.279999971, -2.279999971, -2.279999971, -3.650000095, -3.190000057, 
-3.190000057, 0.879999995, -2.279999971, -2.279999971, -3.650000095, 
-3.190000057, -3.190000057, 4.800000191, 0.879999995, 0.879999995, 
-3.650000095, -3.190000057, -3.190000057, 4.800000191, 4.800000191, 
0.879999995, -3.650000095, -3.190000057, -3.190000057, 4.800000191, 
-2.980000019, -5.210000038, -3.650000095, -7.320000172, -3.190000057, 
4.800000191, -2.980000019, -3.859999895, -6.599999905, -1.75999999, 
-3.970000029, -5.820000172, -2.980000019, -3.859999895, -6.599999905, 
-5.75, -4.039999962, -4.25, -3.869999886, -5.980000019, -5.75, 
-5.75, -4.039999962, -5.380000114, -2.549999952, -2.880000114, 
-5.75, -5.75, -5.380000114, -1.070000052, -1.070000052, -0.419999987, 
-5.820000172, -7.03000021, -3.650000095, -1.070000052, -9.68999958, 
-9.68999958, -5.820000172, -7.03000021, -3.650000095, -5.489999771, 
-3.779999971, 2.230000019, -5.820000172, -7.03000021, -3.650000095, 
-5.489999771, -3.779999971, -1.379999995, -5.820000172, -7.03000021, 
-7.179999828, -5.380000114, -7.5, -6.769999981, -4.349999905, 
-2.539999962, -3.559999943, -9.090000153, -4.480000019, -4.559999943, 
-8.279999733, 5.21999979, -9.039999962, -2.369999886, -2.5, -4.139999866, 
-1.679999948, 7.170000076, 0.419999987, -2.789999962, -5.190000057, 
-7.570000172, 3.769999981, 3.769999981, 0.419999987, 1.720000029, 
-0.959999979, 6.289999962, -1.669999957, 8.489999771, 11.25, 
-5.420000076, -5.420000076, 6.289999962, -6.130000114, -6.130000114, 
11.25, 14.69999981, 12.14999962, 14.40999985, 0.839999974, 0.839999974, 
-4.480000019, -14.76000023, -14.76000023, -1.230000019, 11.61999989, 
11.61999989, 10.61999989, -14.76000023, -14.76000023, -8.479999542, 
11.61999989, 11.61999989, 10.61999989, 2.970000029, -3.170000076, 
-8.479999542, 11.61999989, -0.01, -3.450000048, -3.450000048, 
-5.289999962, -4.619999886, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, 0.109999999, 
0.529999971, -0.400000006, 1.710000038, 1.710000038, 1.710000038, 
-0.360000014, 0.939999998, -0.400000006, -0.400000006, -0.400000006, 
0.829999983, 17.43000031, 8.220000267, -16.95999908, 14.64000034, 
-0.400000006, 9.770000458, 2.410000086, -6.5, -16.95999908, 8.130000114, 
14.64000034, -10.48999977, -14.42000008, -9.680000305, -4.110000134, 
-1.480000019, -0.829999983, -21.45000076, 6.940000057, -16.37000084, 
22.75, 22.75, 11.73999977, 15.78999996, -8.840000153, 5.090000153, 
22.75, 22.75, 0.629999995, 5.769999981, 5.429999828, -1.25, 22.75, 
22.75, 0.629999995, 5.769999981, 5.429999828, -1.25, 22.75, 0.629999995, 
5.769999981, 5.769999981, 5.429999828, 5.429999828, 22.75, 5.769999981, 
5.769999981, 5.429999828, 5.429999828, -4.840000153, 2.099999905, 
4.010000229, 11.78999996, 11.78999996, 3.210000038, -7.110000134, 
2.099999905, 4.010000229, 11.78999996, 11.78999996, 3.210000038, 
3.210000038, 2.099999905, 4.010000229, 12.85999966, 11.78999996, 
10.14999962, -3.180000067, 2.099999905, 4.010000229, 12.85999966, 
11.78999996, 10.14999962, 1.429999948, 2.099999905, 4.010000229, 
6.809999943, 3.539999962, -5.090000153, 6.360000134, 1.779999971, 
7.309999943, -9.149999619, 1.419999957, -1.49000001, -0.980000019, 
-0.579999983, -1.25999999, -14.05000019, 8.220000267, 0.200000003, 
0.159999996, 4.019999981, 6.570000172, 7.989999771, -6.239999771, 
0.899999976, 0.829999983, -1, -3.630000114, -0.889999986, -12.05000019, 
15.03999996, 5.849999905), .Dim = c(6L, 61L))`

```
`dput(head(V))` =`structure(c(-20.85000038, -20.85000038, -20.85000038, -20.85000038,
```

-20.85000038, -20.85000038, -20.85000038, -20.85000038, -20.85000038, 
-20.85000038, -20.85000038, -20.85000038, -20.85000038, -20.85000038, 
-20.85000038, -20.85000038, -20.85000038, -18.28000069, -18.28000069, 
-18.28000069, -18.28000069, -18.28000069, -18.28000069, -2.059999943, 
-2.059999943, -2.059999943, -2.059999943, -2.059999943, -2.059999943, 
-2.059999943, -7.460000038, -7.460000038, -7.460000038, -7.460000038, 
-7.460000038, -7.460000038, -3.829999924, -3.829999924, -3.829999924, 
-3.829999924, -3.829999924, -3.829999924, 3.710000038, 3.710000038, 
3.710000038, 3.710000038, 3.710000038, 3.710000038, 9.899999619, 
9.899999619, 1.710000038, 1.710000038, -20.96999931, -20.96999931, 
1.820000052, 11.43999958, 9.899999619, 9.899999619, 1.710000038, 
1.710000038, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 11.43999958, 
11.43999958, 9.899999619, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 
1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 
1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 
1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 
1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 
2.630000114, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 1.820000052, 
2.630000114, 2.630000114, -0.310000002, 0.039999999, 1.019999981, 
1.019999981, 1.019999981, 0.460000008, -0.310000002, 0.039999999, 
0.039999999, 1.019999981, 1.019999981, 1.019999981, -0.310000002, 
0.039999999, 0.039999999, -6.039999962, 1.019999981, 1.019999981, 
-0.310000002, 0.039999999, 0.039999999, 2.380000114, -6.039999962, 
-6.039999962, -0.310000002, 0.039999999, 0.039999999, 2.380000114, 
2.380000114, -6.039999962, -0.310000002, 0.039999999, 0.039999999, 
2.380000114, -0.600000024, 1.090000033, -0.310000002, 2.369999886, 
0.039999999, 2.380000114, -0.600000024, 1.269999981, 0.289999992, 
1, -0.620000005, -1.429999948, -0.600000024, 1.269999981, 0.289999992, 
0.639999986, -0.430000007, -1.480000019, -1.159999967, -4.860000134, 
0.639999986, 0.639999986, -0.430000007, -8.329999924, -5.079999924, 
2.809999943, 0.639999986, 0.639999986, -8.329999924, 6.210000038, 
6.210000038, -4.679999828, 1.320000052, 2.109999895, 1, 6.210000038, 
5.960000038, 5.960000038, 1.320000052, 2.109999895, 1, 1.620000005, 
2.029999971, -0.200000003, 1.320000052, 2.109999895, 1, 1.620000005, 
2.029999971, 1.389999986, 1.320000052, 2.109999895, 4.400000095, 
0.050000001, 2.720000029, 4.110000134, 2.309999943, 1.850000024, 
-0.029999999, -1.830000043, 1.700000048, -2.930000067, 0.01, 
2.839999914, 3.00999999, -0.529999971, -0.330000013, -1.409999967, 
2.430000067, -2.650000095, 1.080000043, -0.050000001, -0.239999995, 
-0.439999998, 5.53000021, 5.53000021, 1.080000043, 5, -5.590000153, 
9.93999958, -7.989999771, 9.210000038, 9.789999962, -16.19000053, 
-16.19000053, 9.93999958, -13.01000023, -13.01000023, 9.789999962, 
3.289999962, 1.24000001, -6.099999905, 7.699999809, 7.699999809, 
0.029999999, 0.180000007, 0.180000007, 4.449999809, -3.539999962, 
-3.539999962, -3.799999952, 0.180000007, 0.180000007, 1.019999981, 
-3.539999962, -3.539999962, -3.799999952, 1.730000019, -1.00999999, 
1.019999981, -3.539999962, 3.980000019, -1.159999967, -1.159999967, 
3.890000105, 2.460000038, 3.980000019, 3.980000019, 3.980000019, 
3.980000019, -0.870000005, 0.50999999, -1.080000043, 0.930000007, 
0.930000007, 0.930000007, 3.299999952, -1.470000029, -1.080000043, 
-1.080000043, -1.080000043, -5.800000191, -11.10999966, -4.320000172, 
-5.239999771, -3.579999924, -1.080000043, -1.789999962, -4.179999828, 
-5.409999847, -5.239999771, -10.81000042, -3.579999924, 11.25, 
-6.46999979, -3.369999886, 0.860000014, 4.610000134, 8.699999809, 
5.78000021, -4.829999924, 9.789999962, 5.420000076, 5.420000076, 
5.28000021, -5.150000095, 10.21000004, 4.309999943, 5.420000076, 
5.420000076, 0.079999998, 3.390000105, 1.470000029, -5.699999809, 
5.420000076, 5.420000076, 0.079999998, 3.390000105, 1.470000029, 
-5.699999809, 5.420000076, 0.079999998, 3.390000105, 3.390000105, 
1.470000029, 1.470000029, 5.420000076, 3.390000105, 3.390000105, 
1.470000029, 1.470000029, -6.989999771, 0, 0.810000002, -4.539999962, 
-4.539999962, 0.529999971, 0.629999995, 0, 0.810000002, -4.539999962, 
-4.539999962, 0.529999971, 0.529999971, 0, 0.810000002, 1.299999952, 
-4.539999962, -3.059999943, 1.649999976, 0, 0.810000002, 1.299999952, 
-4.539999962, -3.059999943, 0.959999979, 0, 0.810000002, -3.230000019, 
0.379999995, 4.71999979, 0.800000012, -4.909999847, -3.75, 1.99000001, 
-4.139999866, 2.799999952, 5.139999866, -3, -1.25999999, 12.77999973, 
-5.489999771, 6.840000153, 0.889999986, -0.07, 4.619999886, -8.670000076, 
4.639999866, -2.569999933, -2.380000114, 0.170000002, -2.190000057, 
3.930000067, -0.680000007, -0.460000008, -4.639999866), .Dim = c(6L, 
61L))`

Comment: I would assume `quiver` needs all the lengths of `lon`,`lat`,`U`, and `V` to be the same length. Is that the case? What scale are `U` and `V` in compared to `lon` and `lat`?

Comment: Post code. Post code. Post code. Post more code.

Comment: You are not going to get very much attention unless you post your code that did the input process and created the data vectors. Did you use `attach`? Show us output of `dput(head(lon))`, `dput(head(lat))`, `dput(head(U))`, dput(head(V))`

Comment: Thanks BondedDust, I added the info you asked for. My apologies for giving them in the first place.

Comment: Mr Flick, thank you for the reply. That makes sense now that they have to have the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i'm going to assume that `length(lat)==61`, `length(lon)=121` `dim(U)=c(61,121)` and `dim(V)=c(61,121)`. If so, those are not of compatible length for plotting, but you can repeat the `lat` and `lon` values enough to match up. Here's one way to plot the data with base graphics (here i'm just going to use `arrows` rather than `quiver` because this is basically all that function was doing)

```
lat=seq(-10,10,length.out=20)
lon=seq(-10,10,length.out=60)
u=matrix(runif(length(lat)*length(lon),-2,2),nrow=length(lat))
v=matrix(runif(length(lat)*length(lon),-2,2),nrow=length(lat))


scale<-1
plot(0,0,xlim=c(-10,10), ylim=c(-10,10), type="n")
arrows(lat[row(u)], lon[col(u)], 
    lat[row(u)] + scale * u, lon[col(u)] + scale * v, 
    angle = 10, length=.12)
```

Now i've made the matrices smaller so it's not as crazy a mess. But the `length=` and `angle=` settings affect how the head of the arrow is draw. The coordinates you pass determine the length of the shaft

[image: resulting image]